# ssh command is showing no such file or directory when executing within shell script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to run a script in remote machine using ssh.

```
sshpass -p "" ssh abc@remote.com "bash -s" <  path/file.sh
```

When I execute this command normally, It is executing.

But when i put this into another shell script and executing it then it showing

```
no such file or directory
```

I tried putting `#!/bin/bash` in the top of code also.

But no use. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: "no such file or directory" Is this the entire error message? The message should include the name of the file that is missing, and possibly the name of the program that printed the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to Windows line endings. I removed it by using dos2unix command

Answer (score -1):

Actually second time it runs on your local machine not on remote machine try following

```
ssh abc@remote.com "cd /home && ls -l"
```

Comment: When I execute the command you said it is giving                                 
's: invalid option -- '
Try `ls --help' for more information.

Comment: please, post your script @Rajulittlevamp